# How to create a variable and assign another value later in a if statement?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that draws a shape to a screen and I'm having problems trying to make the value of `shapeAngles` equal to a certain value if `sides` (which is an integer from 3 to 10) is `x`.

```py
def shapeDrawer():
    # Gets the sum of the angle from the amounts of sides
    shapeAngles = 0
    if sides == 3:
        shapeAngles = 180
    elif sides == 4:
        shapeAngles = 360
    elif sides == 5:
        shapeAngles = 540
    elif sides == 6:
        shapeAngles = 720
    elif sides == 7:
        shapeAngles = 900
    elif sides == 8:
        shapeAngles = 1080
    elif sides == 9:
        shapeAngles = 1260
    elif sides == 10:
        shapeAngles = 1440
    print("Sum of angles in shape is " + str(shapeAngles))

shapeDrawer()
```

When I inputed 6, I was expecting 720 but I got 0.

Comment: Where does the variable `sides` come from in your code? I'm guessing the `sides` you inputted remained a string and didn't match any of the `elif` cases.

Comment: What means "inputed"? There is no "input" call or setting of "sides".

Comment: You don't need a giant `if` statement; there's a formula that maps the number of sides to the sum of the angles: `shapeAngles = (sides - 2) * 180`.

Comment: You should provide the code for a runnable [mre] in your questions so folks don't have to guess at what you've done.

Answer (score 2):

You probably read a string-representation of a number, and you think it's a number.

In your input (wherever this might be), add this before the condition-checking:

```
input_number = int(input_number)
```

(standard input is by default string)

Comment: Just to be a bit more clear. You would need to convert the string representation of the number (that you got from the input) into a number so that it is treated as a number. Otherwise, you would be saying if sides == 3 and the computer is treating that variables as a string ("3"). Just make sure to convert it to an integer before using it.

Answer (score 0):

There might be 2 problems:

- You said you have inputted the value, but `input` functions takes input in form of string. So you have to use `int(input())` to convert it to a integer or you have check conditions with string i.e `if side=='1': prin(1)`.
- You haven't used `global` keyword to make changes or to read a global variable. If your variable is outside the function, you have to use `global variable_name` to access it inside the function.

I have noticed a pattern in your code that is `angle=num_of_side-2*180`. So intead of using all that if statements, use

```
print(f"Sum of angles in shape is {(int(sides)-2)*180}")
```

Comment: Thanks, you just forgot to turn `sides` into a int.

Comment: Oh yeah you are correct